# Perforce p4 sync command fails for a folder which has a space in it's name

Tags: perl, perforce

There is a folder with the name **Test Logs**. As it can be seen there is a space between Test and Logs
When I try to get it locally using sync command in perl script it fails.

The script has the code:

```
system("p4 sync -f //depot/Test Logs/OnTargetLogs/...");
```

I get the following error:

```
>     //depot/Test - no such file(s).
>     Logs/OnTargetLogs/... - no such file(s).
```

Comment: Quote the argument maybe? `system("p4 sync -f \"//depot/Test Logs/OnTargetLogs/...\"");`

Comment: What you said worked. Also I found another way of doing this :
`my @a1 = ("p4","sync","-f","//depot/Test Logs/OnTargetLogs/...");`
`system @a1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the argument maybe?

```
system("p4 sync -f \"//depot/Test Logs/OnTargetLogs/...\"");
```

– Sobrique

What you said worked. Also I found another way of doing this :

```
my @a1 = ("p4","sync","-f","//depot/Test Logs/OnTargetLogs/..."); system @a1;
```

– Vishal Khemani